# Prevent display of Arraylist values twice in java

Tags: java, jsp, arraylist, jstl

I have a method which returns an arraylist. But the Arraylsit is displaying its values twice.
The code is-

```
ArrayList<Double> ref_jsp=new ArrayList<Double>();

public  ArrayList<Double> refernece(String name) throws SQLException, ParseException {

    String first=name.substring(1,19);
    String last =name.substring(24,42);
   List<Double> slist = new ArrayList<Double>(map1.keySet());
  String s = StringUtils.join(slist, ',');
  System.out.println("comma separated string"+s);

       try
            {  
              con = getConnection();
              stmt = con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE,ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);

             String vs2="SQL Query"
             stmt.executeQuery(vs2);
             rs1 = stmt.getResultSet();

             while(rs1.next()) 
                {
                   ref_jsp.add((rs1.getDouble(1)));
                   ref_jsp.add((rs1.getDouble(2)));
                   ref_jsp.add((rs1.getDouble(3)));
                   ref_jsp.add((rs1.getDouble(4)));
                   ref_jsp.add((rs1.getDouble(5)));
                   ref_jsp.add((rs1.getDouble(6)));
                   ref_jsp.add(rs1.getDouble(7));
                   ref_jsp.add(rs1.getDouble(8));
                   ref_jsp.add(rs1.getDouble(9));
                   ref_jsp.add(rs1.getDouble(10));
                   ref_jsp.add((rs1.getDouble(11)));

            }  
         }
        catch( Exception e )
                {
                    System.out.println("\nException in reference "+e);
                }
        return ref_jsp;
    }
```

My Sql query is fine.I checked it.The values returned by ref_jsp are displayed twice.Please explain where I'm going wrong??My jsp code foe displaying list values is-

```
<%
 String ref_name= request.getParameter("ref_logtime");
 pageContext.setAttribute("ref_name", ref_name);
 ref.FindClosestToMultiplesOfTen(ref_name);
 ref.refernece(ref_name);
%>
<table width = "300px" border = "1" cellspacing="2">

 <tr><c:forEach var="r" items="${ref.refernece(param.ref_logtime)}"> 
 <td><c:out value="${r}"></c:out></td>
 </c:forEach></tr>
 </table>
```

My output is of the form-

```
 value-1 value-2 value-3 value-4 value-1 value-2 value-3 value-4
```

Comment: Can you show us your output screen ?

Comment: I don' really understand what's the role of scriplets in your jsp?

Comment: Actually,I have another jsp page  on which a calender is displayed .User selects the date from the calendar and that date goes to the sql query.So I used scriplet to pass selected date from that jsp to java class and the required method.

Comment: @SanKrish I can't show image of my output as my reputation is below 10.But please see my edit above.I tried to give a view of my output.

Comment: Are you sure, that call to method reference, passing the parameter ref_logtime returns the ArrayList which contains only 1,2,3,4 values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like problem is because of the following line in your java class.

```
ArrayList<Double> ref_jsp = new ArrayList<Double>();
```

You have declared `ref_jsp` as class level variable, move it inside the method `public  ArrayList<Double> refernece(String name)`.

It is happening because you are calling your `referenece` method twice from the jsp.

```
<%
 String ref_name= request.getParameter("ref_logtime");
 pageContext.setAttribute("ref_name", ref_name);
 ref.FindClosestToMultiplesOfTen(ref_name);
 ref.refernece(ref_name); //******* 1st call *********
%>
<table width = "300px" border = "1" cellspacing="2">

 <tr><c:forEach var="r" items="${ref.refernece(param.ref_logtime)}">//***2nd call*** 
 <td><c:out value="${r}"></c:out></td>
 </c:forEach></tr>
 </table>
```

During the 1st call suppose you got 10 items and those got added in your arraylist, and since that arraylist is a instance level variable, during the second call you again got 10 items and that got added along with the existing 10, hence you are having duplicate items.

Comment: Ok.But I can't put ArrayList<Double> ref_jsp = new ArrayList<Double>(); in my method as ref_jsp is being used in other method.As refernece(String name) has argument ,I don't no how to call this method in another method so that I can declare ref_jsp  in refernece(String name) method.

Comment: declare a new `ref_jsp1` inside your method, add resultset values to it and return this `ref_jsp1` back to the calee.

Comment: @tiddirastogi OR as a quick fix add `ref_jsp.clear()` in the first line of your `refernece` method.

Answer (score 0):

@Zeeshan pointed the mistake correctly. If you don't want to the make the arraylist being returned as a local member of the function and as you mentioned ref_jsp is being used in another method also, make sure to clear the elements of arraylist when all your associated methods are done operating on that list. Use ref_jsp.clear() for that.